# Parsing HTML with XPath, Python and Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am writing a Scrapy program to extract the data.

[This is the url](http://deepstylekorea.com/shop/step1.php?number=1345), and I want to scrape `20111028013117` (code) information. I have taken XPath from FireFox add-on [XPather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpather/). This is the path:

```
/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

While I am trying to execute this

```
try:
    temp_list = hxs.select("/html/body/p/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").extract()
    print "temp_list:" + str(temp_list)
except:
    print "error"
```

It returns an empty list, I am struggling to find out an answer for this from the last 4 hours. I am a newbie to scrapy eventhough I handled issues very well for other projects, but it seems to be a bit difficult.

Answer (score 9):

The reason of why your xpath doesn't work is becuase of `tbody`. You have to remove it and check if you get that result that you want.

You can read this in scrapy documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/firefox.html

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding `<tbody>` elements to
>   tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page
>   HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use `<tbody>` in
>   your XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks for posting the excerpt from the Scrapy docs. It might improve the answer to suggest a replacement path which would work better.

Comment: Chrome adds <tbody>, too. Just got my code working after I saw this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see that the element you are hunting for is inside a `<table>`.

[Firefox adds `tbody` tag for every table, even if it does not exists in source HTML code](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/b3f9b0893c1ad7e1?pli=1). 
That's might be the reason, that your xpath query works in the browser, but fails in Scrapy.

As suggested, use other anchors in your xpath query.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract data with more ease using more robust XPaths instead of taking the direct output from XPather.

For the data you are matching, this XPath would do a lot better:

```
//font[contains(text(),'Code')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/font/text()
```

This will match the `<font>` tag containing "Code", then go to the `td` tag above it and select the next `td` -> `font`, which contains the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing a few node tags at the end of the query, and re-running until you get a result? Do this several times until you get something, then add items back in cautiously until the query is rectified.

Also, check that your target page validates as XHTML - an invalid page would probably upset the parser.