# Scrapy - incrementing number in a string

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

Again I seem to have a brick wall with this one and I'm hoping somebody would be able to answer it off the top of their head.

Here's an example code below:

```
def parse_page(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    item = response.meta['item']
    item["Details_H1"] = hxs.select('//*[@id="ctl09_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps"]/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

It seems that the `@id` in the `Details_H1` could change. E.G. For a page it could be `@id="ctl08_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps` and for the next page it's randomly `@id="ctl09_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps`.

I would like to implement a `do until` loop equivalent such that the code cycles through the numbers with increments of 1 until the value being yielded by the XPath is non-zero. So for example I could set i=108 and would i=i+1 each time until `hxs.select('//*[@id="ctl09_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps"]/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()` <> []

How would I be able to implement this?

Your help and contribution is greatly appreciated

**EDIT 1**

Fix addressed by TNT below. Code should read:

```
def parse_page(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    item = response.meta['item']
    item["Details_H1"] = hxs.select('//*[contains(@id, "_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps")]/tr[1]/td[1]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

Comment: Use a global variable or an argument that serves as a counter, and format your string to fit that.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with python syntax. Could you please provide me with an example or link me to an article where it's covered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'natural' XPATH way would be to more generalize your xpath expresssion:

```
xp = '//*[contains(@id, "_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps")]/tr[1]/td[1]/text()'
item["Details_H1"] = hxs.select(xp).extract()
```

But I'm groping in the dark. Your xpath expression would probably better begin with something like  `//table` or `//tbody`

In any case a "do until" would be ugly.

Comment: I'll try your approach too and will report back! Reason why I removed the `//tbody` is because I wasn't able to pull any results as per this post here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941060/parsing-html-with-xpath-python-scrapy). Cheers

Comment: Just tried it and it works a treat! I have edited my code above (in my initial post) to reflect the fix. Just as an FYI, is there any way to have an `OR` function for the `contains`. I.E. Let's say if it contains `"ctl17"` or `"ctl01_ctl00_dlProps"`. Is it as easy as `[contains(@id, "ctl17", "ctl01_ctl00_dlProps")]`? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
i = 108
while True:
    item = response.meta['item']
    xpath = '//*[@id="ct%d_p_ctl17_ctl04_ctl01_ctl00_dlProps"]/tr[1]/td[1]/text()' %i
    item["Details_H1"] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()
    if not item["Details_H1"]:
        break
    i += 1
    yield item
```

Comment: Hi omair,

I tried the code you wrote but it's not working on my end. I changed the i=8 and the xpath='//*[@id="ctl0%d_p_c.....' %i since it's l08 not 108. I even tried changing the indent position of yield item

Do you have any other suggestions? I appreciate your help

Comment: EDIT: Should there be an i = i + 1 somewhere?

Comment: can you specify what problem is it causing?

Comment: I'll try the new syntax tonight. It wasn't producing any output. Are you able to edit your code to include the `def parse_page(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)`? I just need to know how the indentation should look. I also assume `return item` is replaced with `yield item`

Comment: Still couldn't get it to work. Do you have a full code you'd be able to supply as a demonstration? That way I could also get better context. Thanks