# No Output from Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape some data from a list of urls for example http://basketball.realgm.com/international/league/12/French-LNB-Pro-A/teams to pull all of the team names. Below is my spider, it is running through the URLs but not taking any data?

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from teams.items import TeamsItem

class TeamsSpider(Spider):
    name = "teamcrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["basketball.realgm.com"]
    f = open("teamurls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = TeamsItem()
            item["URL"] = title.select("td[1]/a/@href").extract()
            item["Team"] = title.select("td[1]/a/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        print items
        return items
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is failing because of the `tbody` in the XPath. Browsers (like Firefox and Chrome) will add that node to tables if it isn't present in the source of the page.

Since the `tbody` node might or might not be in the source of the page, you can use scrapy shell to perform interactive debugging with what scrapy sees. Usage: `scrapy shell 'http://www.example.org'`

Related question: [Parsing HTML with XPath, Python and Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941060/parsing-html-with-xpath-python-scrapy)